# what is invalidate,update methods do in VC++

Tags: c++, mfc, winapi, windows-services, visual-c++

i have small doubt regarding the window functions in c++.
what exactly `"invalidate()"` function do?
what message does it sends?when we need to call this? also what is `"update()"` function?
is `"invalidaterect()"` works similar to `"invalidate()"` function?.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`CWnd::Invalidate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ax04k970%28VS.80%29.aspx) invalidates the entire client area of a window, which indicates that the area is out of date, and should be repainted. You would typically call this on a control that needs to be redrawn. [`CWnd::InvalidateRect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2f3csed3%28VS.80%29.aspx) invalidates only part of the window.

With the `Invalidate` functions, the `WM_PAINT` message will posted [*not strictly true; see the comments*] to the message queue and handled at some point in the future. [`CWnd::UpdateWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yz8we9y%28VS.71%29.aspx) sends (as opposed to posts) a `WM_PAINT` message, causing the invalidated regions to be redrawn immediately.

Really, this is all in the docs.

Comment: you mean, we should not call "Invalidate" or "CWnd::UpdateWindow()"
at one instance in application right?
we need to call either one of it right to get wm_paint message

Comment: Indeed. Calling both is not necessary. You would typically call `UpdateWindow` only if the same thread would do some lengthy computation afterwards, so it wouldn't get back to its message loop soon enough. In that case you want to repaint immediately, not wait until a more convenient time. But in general, use `Invalidate`.

Comment: Actually, `WM_PAINT` isn't posted. An internal flag is just set in the window manager and that flag is checked by `::Peek/GetMessage` in the message pump. If the flag is set and no higher priority messages are in the queue, `WM_PAINT` is returned in the `MSG` structure.

Comment: In practice, you probably won't be able to tell the difference. But thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @JohannGerell Thanks. Then what's the difference between "post" and "set flag"?

Comment: @starriet To "post" a message means to put a message in the message queue, for "later" retrieval by get/peek message and subsequent handling by a window procedure. To "send" a message means immediately calling a window procedure with a message. To set a flag (in this context) means that the window manager sets a flag "the_window_is_invalidated" when the user calls one of the Win32 APIs that invalidates a window. when all posted higher prio messages are handled, if that flag is found to be set, then the next time get/peek message is called, the window manager returns a WM_PAINT message.

Comment: @JohannGerell Thank you so much. So, "send" is the highest priority(immediate effect), while "setting a flag" is the lowest priority, because all the prior "posted" messages in the queue should be handled first?

Comment: @starriet It might be helpful to know why it's done this way. Other messages in the queue (e.g. user input) often result in more invalidation. If WM_PAINT was posted or sent like any other message, the program would often spend time painting areas that will become out of date immediately after, as a result of these other messages that were enqueued before or during painting. By setting a flag instead, Windows ensures that the message queue is empty, so the program has reached a "steady state" and any painting done will probably not be wasted effort.

Comment: @Thomas Oh, so if a flag is set, that message is handled *only* if the message queue is empty. And your explanation makes sense, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The invalidate function marks the drawing area as invalidated. This flag is used when the window is redrawn, if the area is invalidated it will redraw the area, if not it will just leave the screen area as it is. invalidate invalidates the whole client area of a given object, invalidaterect invalidates a specific region of the client area. The update function does the actual redraw.

The reason for such a mechanism, and not just drawing immediately when you know something has to be changed is that you can prevent multiple redraws, say for example you received three keydown messages in one go, which scroll some text area. If you redrew the text area for each of the key presses you would have to draw the text area three times and the application would become unresponsive. By instead processing all the key events, updating the data structure attached to the text area and invalidating the text area before you redraw the textarea, you only redraw the textarea once.