# C++ function Sleep() executes before piece of code

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I work in Visual Studio with C++, Windows Form App. I try to paint the button red, wait 3 seconds and then paint it blue.

```
button1->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::DarkRed;
Sleep(3000);
button1->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::CornflowerBlue;
```

However, Sleep() functions executes before first line (painting red). Program starts from waiting 3 seconds and after time it paints the button blue. It seems like painting red piece of code doesn't have time to execute. Individually, painting red works fine.
I've tried other delay solutions also. Example:

```
int wait = clock() + 2 * CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
while (clock() < wait) {}
```

It seems to be an issue in Visual Studio C++, because the Sleep() function have worked perfectly in Code::Blocks console script. Do you have any ideas of solution?

Comment: I'm assuming that you are putting the main thread to sleep so it doesn't have time to update the background color to red.

Comment: Sleep function stops program execution for a period of time. In your case it happens before the draw call. You need to use an update function that is run after every draw calls

Comment: The button needs to be forced to redraw itself - it doesn't do that immediately for performance reasons by default, and calling `Sleep()` suspends the thread before that happens.  If you're using .NET - you haven't made that clear - try adding `button1->Refresh()` before the call of `Sleep()`.

Answer (score 0):

Since Button is also a Window you can Invalidate it before calling `Sleep()`.
[what is invalidate,update methods do in VC++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183649/what-is-invalidate-update-methods-do-in-vc)

Answer (score 0):

Setting component properties, eg 'button1->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::DarkRed;' are not trivial assignments.  The setter methods generate messages, or sequences of messages, that are posted to the Windows/thread that implement the GUI.  Those messages must be handled before the requested property set actions can be considered completed.

If you set a window visual property in an event-handler, and then remove all execution from the thread that manages the window before leaving the event-handler, the messages will not get processed.

Do not wait in a GUI event handler.  It's a state-machine for handling messages.  Don't stop it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your contribution guys! 
Advice about threads was helpful. I've solved this problem with the Refresh() function. It seems like parts of code are handled with different threads which work asynchronous. Refresh() function probably implements waiting for the threads to by synchronised.