# How to call OnEraseBkgnd() to repaint the window in another function? (MFC)

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to call `OnEraseBkgnd()` to repaint the window in another function.

For example, like the code below:

```
...

CBitmap Background;
BITMAP bm;
CDC dcMemory;
int width, height;

...

BOOL CSplashDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    CDC* dc;

    Background.LoadBitmap(IDB_COVER);   //Load Bitmap
    Background.GetBitmap(&bm);      //Load Bitmap into handle

    width = 0;
    height = 0;

    while(width < 300)
    {
        width += 10;
        height += 10;
        OnEraseBkgnd(dc);       //<--- Here I want to call OnEraseBkgnd()

        Sleep(5);           //Delay 5 millisecond
    }

    return TRUE;
}



BOOL CSplashDlg::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC)
{
    ///////////////////////////////////
      Invalidate();             //I don't know where I should put this function
    ///////////////////////////////////

    dcMemory.CreateCompatibleDC(pDC);
    CBitmap *pOldbmp = dcMemory.SelectObject(&Background);

    pDC->SetStretchBltMode(HALFTONE);

    pDC->StretchBlt(0, 0, width, height, &dcMemory, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, SRCCOPY);

    return TRUE;
}
```

In the above example, I want to call `OnEraseBkgnd()` to repaint the window while executing inside `OnInitDialog()`. I have searched the Internet and it always says using `Invalidate();` or `RedrawWindow();` to repaint it and it'll also call the `OnEraseBkgnd()` function. The question is: How should I use the `Invalidate();` or the `RedrawWindow();`? Where should I put those function?

I have put those two functions in anywhere but it still not works.

**EDIT:**

I have modified it. Though now `Invalidate()` and `UpdateWindow()` are success to call the `OnEraseBkgnd()` function. But I found another problem: Why didn't the `StretchBlt` work when I used `Invalidate()` or `UpdateWindow()` to repaint it but did the `FillSolidRect` work?

```
...

BOOL CMainDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CSplashDlg Frame;

    Frame.width = 0;
    Frame.height = 0;

    while(Frame.width <= 300)
    {
        Frame.width += 10;
        Frame.height += 10;

        Frame.Invalidate();     //<---Here I use both Invalidate() and UpdateWindow()
        Frame.UpdateWindow();       //<---Here I use both Invalidate() and UpdateWindow()

        Sleep(5);           //Delay 5 millisecond
    }

    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    return TRUE;
}

BOOL CSplashDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    width = 0;
    height = 0;

    Background.LoadBitmap(IDB_COVER);   //Load Bitmap
    Background.GetBitmap(&bm);      //Load Bitmap into handle


    return TRUE;
}



BOOL CSplashDlg::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC)
{
    dcMemory.CreateCompatibleDC(pDC);
    CBitmap *pOldbmp = dcMemory.SelectObject(&Background);

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    pDC->SetStretchBltMode(HALFTONE);
    pDC->StretchBlt(0, 0, width, height, &dcMemory, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, SRCCOPY);        //It doesn't work when using this one (StretchBlt)
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    pDC->FillSolidRect(0, 0, width, height, RGB(255,0,0));                      //But it works when using this one (FillSolidRect)
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    return TRUE;
}

...
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183649/what-is-invalidate-update-methods-do-in-vc

Comment: Dialog is not visible until `OnInitDialog` returns.  What you can do in `OnInitDialog` is to create a timer for 5 milliseconds `SetTimer(1, 5, 0)`, add `ON_WM_TIMER` to message map, then in `OnTimer(UINT_PTR)` call `Invalidate()`. Do the painting in `OnPaint`, not in `OnEraseBkgnd`

Comment: In your second edit, everything is correct, except, after `Frame->Invalidate` the Windows messages are blocked, it doesn't update the window because the system is still processing another message (`WM_INITDIALOG`). You call `UpdateWindow` after it, hoping to convince Windows to process the message, but it still doesn't do it. The only option is to insert a message loop in between (with `PeekMessage`), to process current messages which are in message queue, but you have to be careful. Or do this using `WM_TIMER`

Answer (score 3):

You should never call the likes of `OnEraseBkgnd( )` and `OnPaint( )`. MFC will call these when drawing is needed. Your job is to handle the need to draw in `OnEraseBkgnd( )`.

`Invalidate( )` causes MFC to update the drawing area and then it will call `OnEraseBkgnd( )` and `OnPaint( )`. If you `Invalidate( )` in `OnPaint( )` or `OnEraseBkgnd( )` the program will likely hang as it would cause an endless loop of redrawing the window.

You can call `Invalidate( )` in `OnInitDialog( )` but it is likely unnecessary.

So take the Invalidate out of `OnEraseBkgnd( )`, don't call `OnEraseBkgnd( )` in `OnInitDialog( )` and go from there.

You also have to have

`ON_WM_PAINT( )
ON_WM_ERASEBKGND( )`

in your message map for those to be called by MFC.

**NOTE:**
I'm not a believer in reinventing wheels. It has mostly been done before. I have not used a splash screen in my projects, but if I were to, I would start here: [Splash Screen C++ Class using MFC](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/35840/splash-screen-c-class-using-mfc).

I didn't download and review the code but with four stars, it should be a good place to start. MFC is not an overnight learn. When I started I read books and tons of searches to learn. You just can not make guesses about how the infrastructure works. Hope this helps...

Comment: I have put `Invalidate()` in `OnInitDialog()` and add `ON_WM_ERASEBKGND()` into the message map but it still doesn't repaint anything.

Comment: @BananaCode Calling `Invalidate` just marks the window for repainting.  To see the change you need to either call `UpdateWindow` after invalidating, don't invalidate and call `RedrawWindow`, or run a message loop after invalidating.

Comment: I found another problem: Why didn't `StretchBlt` work when I used `Invalidate()` or `UpdateWindow()` but did `FillSolidRect` work? The code is in the updated content.

Comment: Then this tells you that the issue is likely with the bitmap. Are you sure IDB_COVER is a valid resource? I can't see anything else, your code should work. I'm 'fairly' sure I didn't miss something.